# Unity: How to destroy an Instantiated object in a different function

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a game which is spawning an object and after the object is destroyed, another object spawns right away. But right now I'm trying to destroy an instantiate object in a different function, and it is not working.

`

```
    public GameObject[] food;
    public Vector3Int spawnPosition;

    public void Start()
    {
        SpawnFood();
    }

    //Spawning food 
    public void SpawnFood()
    {
        int random = Random.Range(0, food.Length);
        GameObject clone = (GameObject)Instantiate(food[random], this.spawnPosition, Quaternion.identity);
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.C))
        {
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
        }
    }
```

`

I have tried to do some research on this and still, I can only find the solution for destroying an object inside the same function as the Instantiate.

Comment: At want point as you calling `SpawnFood()`? The post isn’t really clear about the process steps you’re taking in your code, and the code presented doesn’t paint a full picture.

Comment: Sorry, I have edited it.

Comment: It's not a solution exactly but if you want to destroy one and spawn other, why not just changing position instead?

Comment: I think @Daniel has right. Instead of destroying and instantiating the same object, it is better to just disable it to create the illusion of destroying it, change its position, and then enable it again. Or even better, you can use an object pooling design pattern, which is also a best practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `Destroy(this.gameObject)`, the game object the script attacting to will be destroyed, and after that you cannot call the script.

I guess what you want to destroy is the `food` game object, not the game object the script you showed here attacting to.

A quick adjustment to suit your need maybe :

```
...
private GameObject clone
...
private void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.C))
    {
        if (clone != null)
          Destroy(clone);
    }
}
```

And as @Daniel seggested, if you will repeatedly instantiate/destroy food game object, the better way would be just use the same food object and change it's properties (e.g. location...) to create the `new food game object pop-up illusion`.

The key idea here is called [Object Pooling](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Pool.ObjectPool_1.html).

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer :

declare a public Gameobject:

```
public GameObject clone;
```

and replace

```
GameObject clone = (GameObject)Instantiate(food[random], this.spawnPosition, Quaternion.identity);
```

with

```
GameObject clone = Instantiate(food[random], this.spawnPosition, Quaternion.identity);
```

and then you can destroy in another function or class

```
public void DestroyFood()
{

Destroy(clone);

//you can instantiate another gameobject here

}
```